# How to show code only on last page of post in wordpress? (Conditional Coding)

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to make a snippet work in my theme. Here is the code:

```
<?php if ($paged == $wp_query->max_num_pages){
   echo do_shortcode('[taq_review]'); 
}
?>
```

The purpose of the code is show the shortcode only on the last page of my WordPress post. My WordPress post has 6 pages and the code should only output on the last page. This doesn't seem to be working. Can anybody suggest what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need is this:

```
$total_post_page_count = substr_count( $post->post_content, '<!--nextpage-->' ) + 1;
$currentPage           = isset($wp_query->query_vars['page']) ?  (int)$wp_query->query_vars['page'] : 1;

if ($currentPage == $total_post_page_count)
{
    echo do_shortcode('[taq_review]'); 
}
```

Hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

This should now check the current page number against the max number of pages and then echo the shortcode.

```
if ($wp_query->max_num_pages == $wp_query->get( 'paged' )){

    echo do_shortcode('[taq_review]'); 

}
```

Comment: Thanks for so quick response. The problem is every post have different number of pages. Is it possible to make the code only output on last page of every post?

Comment: @user5621919 I have updated my answer hopefully that should answer your question.

Comment: is it a custom post type per review?